# Unable to resolve the source file for '...Magento_Customer/js/zxcvbn.js.map'

Tags: magento2

I'm running Magento 2.4.0 in developer mode with server-side compilation using PHP Less library.

Console is showing this error in every page:

```
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for https://example.com/pub/static/version1600339825/frontend/Example/default/en_US/Magento_Customer/js/zxcvbn.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
```

I tried to access to `https://example.com/pub/static/version1600339825/frontend/Example/default/en_US/Magento_Customer/js/zxcvbn.js.map` through the browser and it says:

```
Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/Example/default/en_US/Magento_Customer/js/zxcvbn.js.map'
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:263]
#2 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/static.php:13]
</pre>
```

I checked also the file `https://example.com/pub/static/version1600339825/frontend/Example/default/en_US/Magento_Customer/js/zxcvbn.js` and it exists.

---

#### What I tried

I thought the error was generated by a file merging so I tried to exclude `zxcvbn.js` from it adding this row in my theme `etc/view.xml`:

```
<item type="file">Magento_Customer::js/zxcvbn.js</item> <!-- It was already present -->
<item type="file">Magento_Customer::js/zxcvbn.min.js</item>
<item type="file">Magento_Customer::js/zxcvbn.js.map</item>
```

but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: i am also getting the same error did u get any solution?

Comment: @NavinBhudiya No, I didn't. However, I just upgraded to Magento 2.4.1 but the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is only one solution:
Copy the file js/zxcvbn.js into your own template directory: Magento_Customer::js/zxcvbn.js and delete at the end in the file "//# sourceMappingURL=zxcvbn.js.map

Comment: I copied it here `app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Customer/web/js/zxcvbn.js` and I removed `//# sourceMappingURL=zxcvbn.js.map` at the end of the file but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Have you removed the static content and setup:static-content:deploy?

Comment: I'm in developer mode. Anyway, I removed `pub/static/frontend/` and cleared the cache but nothing's changed.